# Retrieve bash version in AIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, aix

After the shellshock issue detected on Unix systems with bash, I have to create a script as part of my internship in a firm in order to update bash.

Prerequisites to the installation of the updated IBM bash*.rpm are:

- having bash installed (simple check)
- having bash version under 4.2.50

I have a problem dealing with the second part, since the true bash version is given by command     `bash -version`     instead of     `rpm -qi bash`     which essentially gives the version/release of the installation package (and not neccessarily the true bash version).

Basically, my script goes like this:

```
if [[ bash installed ]] ; then
  if [[ bash version installed is < 4.2.50 ]] ; then
    install bash version 4.2.50
  fi
fi
```

`bash -version` returns a lot of text, and I would like to pick out the bash version.

So far, I've used the following command:

```
$ bash -version | grep version | awk '{print $4}' | head -n 1
```

That returns :

```
4.2.50(1)-release
```

Is there any way to retrieve the real bash version? I've played around with the `sed` command with no success.

Comment: What's wrong with `4.2.50(1)-release`? What is your expected output? How are you planning to compare it to 4.2.50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to get output like this,

```
$ bash -version | awk -F'[ (]' '/version/{print $4;exit}'
4.3.11
```

Comment: Thank you, this works efficiently and solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can directly use the `$BASH_VERSION` variable:

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
4.2.47(1)-release
```

From `man bash`:

> **Shell Variables**
>
> BASH_VERSION
>
> Expands to a string describing the version of this instance of bash.

---

Then, to check if the version is under or above `4.2.50` you can make use of `sort -V` to order them:

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" 4.2.50 $BASH_VERSION | sort -V
4.2.47(1)-release
4.2.50

$ printf "%s\n%s\n" 4.2.50 5.2.33 | sort -V
4.2.50
5.2.33
```

This should be enough for you to determine if your current bash version is under or above the desired one, just some `head` and `tail` is needed for the final result.

From [`man sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html):

> **-V**, --version-sort
>
> natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Comment: This would be great but unfortunately, $BASH_VERSION does not return anything on my servers (AIX 5.3 to 7.1).

Comment: Uhms, it is a pity. Maybe you can dive into `man bash` and look for some variables in the "Shell variables" section. Or of course write `echo $BASH_` and then press tab to see what variables are available.